# Display a variable inside another with thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I Have a th:each loop where a display buttons.

```
<li th:id="${'button-' + row.name }" th:unless="${row.name == 'linkedin' or row.name == 'slideshow'}" class="collection-item avatar" th:each="row, rowStat: *{arButtons}">
        <img th:src="${'/images/buttons/' + row.name + '.png'}" th:alt="${row.name}" class="circle"/>
            <div class=" input-field col s12">
                <input th:field="*{arButtons[__${rowStat.index}__].name}" type="hidden" />
                <input th:field="*{arButtons[__${rowStat.index}__].data}" th:id="${'button-'+rowStat.index}" type="text" class="validate" /> 
                <label th:if="${row.name == 'call'}" th:for="${'button-'+rowStat.index}" th:text="${call}"> Phone number </label>
                <label th:if="${row.name == 'mail'}" th:for="${'button-'+rowStat.index}" th:text="${mail}"> Email </label>
                <label th:if="${row.name == 'link'}" th:for="${'button-'+rowStat.index}" th:text="${link}"> Web Link </label>
                <label th:if="${row.name == 'video'}" th:for="${'button-'+rowStat.index}" th:text="${video}"> Video </label>
            </div>
        </li>
```

Now i don't want to use every time to check on the row.name in order to display the convient text is there a way to use something like

```
<label th:for="${'button-'+rowStat.index}" th:text="${${row.name}}">  </label>
```

Please any idea !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out Thymeleaf's [preprocessing](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing) capabilities. For your case I think

```
th:text="${__(${row.name})__}"
```

**Note** that you should use double underscores and the parenthesis could be ommited, but makes it more clear for me

Comment: Silly me, it's works ! I didn't realize that processing can be used on variables that way. Thanks a lot !